# How to write with good practice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am trying to create chart with chart.js and I would like to get data to chart from backend, but first I need to call function that exists in my controller. I am trying to call this function from index.html.

**INDEX:**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: $scope.getChartLabels(),
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: $scope.getChartData(),
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
(...)

.controller('DashboardController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getChartLabels = function() {
        return ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"];
    }

    $scope.getChartData = function() {
        return [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];
    }
}

(...)
```

How to call angular function getChartLabels() or getChartData() from index.html without bad practices?

Comment: Is your code correct? Then [codereview.se] site will be better for your question

Comment: Yes, everything is working well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should do otherwise and call the javascript methods to draw chart via angularJs

```
.controller('DashboardController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getChartLabels = function() {
        return ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"];
    }

    $scope.getChartData = function() {
        return [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];
     }

    drawCharts($scope.getChartLabels,$scope.getChartData);
}

    function drawCharts(d1,d2){
      // draw charts here.
    }
```

Comment: Agreed, it should be angular's job to build and maintain the nuts and bolts (and charts) of your user interface, not the other way around.